# Trigger throwing duplicate Id in list while updating

Tags: apex

I have the code which is trying to update records but I am getting error that duplicate Id in list, below is my class

I am getting error at `update clonedPeriods;`

```
 List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> periods = [
        SELECT Id, Rent_Schedule__c
        FROM Rent_Schedule_Period__c
        WHERE Rent_Schedule__c IN :scheduleIds
    ];
    if(periods.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Set<Id> periodIds = new Map<Id, Rent_Schedule_Period__c>(periods).keySet();
    Map<id,List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c>> clonedMap=new Map<id,List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c>>();
   // List<Id> periodIdList = new List<Id>(periodIds);
    List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> clonedPeriods = new CloneService()
        .withSource(new List<Id>(periodIds))
        .deepClone();
   List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> toUpdate=new List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c>();
    Set<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> setrecords=new Set<Rent_Schedule_Period__c>(clonedPeriods);
    List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> uniqueRecords=new List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c>(setrecords);

   String periodId;
    if(rentScheduleId!=null){
     List<Rent_Schedule_Period__c> period=[select id,name from Rent_Schedule_Period__c where Rent_Schedule__c=:rentScheduleId];
        if( period.size()>0){
            for(Rent_Schedule_Period__c pro : period)
            periodId=pro.id;
        }
    }
    system.debug('clonedPeriods.size()=='+clonedPeriods.size());
    for (Integer i = 0; i < clonedPeriods.size(); i++) {
        Rent_Schedule_Period__c clonedPeriod = clonedPeriods.get(i);
        system.debug('periodId=='+periodId);
        system.debug('clonedPeriod=='+clonedPeriod);
        if(periodId!=null){
           clonedPeriod.id=periodId;
        }else{
           clonedPeriod.Rent_Schedule__c =clonedScheduleByOriginalId.get(clonedPeriod.Rent_Schedule__c);
        }
   toUpdate.add(clonedPeriod);
    }
    if(periodId!=null){
        system.debug('uniqueRecords==='+clonedPeriods);
        update clonedPeriods;
        //update RentScheduleService.getPriorPeriodUpdates(toUpdate);
    }else{
        insert clonedPeriods;
       // update RentScheduleService.getPriorPeriodUpdates(clonedPeriods);
    }
    update RentScheduleService.getPriorPeriodUpdates(clonedPeriods);

    RentScheduleService.evaluateAndSave(SObjectUtils.collectIds(clonedSchedules));
}
```

Comment: consider using Sets of sobjects rather than lists to avoid duplicates

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE!  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is a common issue and you can search the site for previous posts and solutions.  If you've already done that and haven't worked out a resolution, please [edit] your post to describe what you've done.